# Thymeleaf date formatters for FileTemplateResolver

Tags: unit-testing, thymeleaf

I successfully integrated Spring 3 date formatters with Thymeleaf which works and ${{date}} is formatted as expected - which is great!

The problem comes when templates are processed with FileTemplateResolver outside Spring Web Application Context. We use FileTemplateResolver to process templates and return HTML code so we can validate it without starting application itself - makes testing process much faster and simpler.

As a result, when processing following fragment with our PagePreview

```
<time data-th-datetime="${{createdOn}}" datetime="2013-04-06T13:53">now</time>
```

It renders as
    `<time datetime="Fri Jan 10 09:02:31 GMT 2014">Fri Jan 10 09:02:31 GMT 2014</time>`

Which is not valid HTML5. Works ok when rendered with Thymeleaf + Spring 3:
    `<time datetime="2014-01-10T09:02">2014-01-10T09:02</time>`

This is the code we use to process templates without web app context:

```
public final class PagePreview {
private static final IWebContext emptyContext = new FakeWebContext();

private static final String templateBaseFolder = "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/thymeleaf-templates/";
private static final TemplateEngine templateEngine = initialiseTemplateEngine();

private static TemplateEngine initialiseTemplateEngine() {
    FileTemplateResolver templateResolver = new FileTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix(templateBaseFolder);
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5");
    templateResolver.setHtml5TemplateModePatterns(Sets.newHashSet("*.html"));
    TemplateEngine engine = new TemplateEngine();
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
    engine.initialize();
    return engine;
}

public static String previewTemplateWithData(String templateName, Data data) {
    Context ctx = new FakeWebContext();
    ctx.setVariables(data.toMap());
    return templateEngine.process(templateName, ctx);
}

public static String previewTemplateOnly(String templateName) {
    return templateEngine.process(templateName, emptyContext);
}
}
```

Any ideas how can we set default formatters for Date objects?